# Oracle function in invalid state error

Tags: oracle

I have oracle function

```
create or replace function payu_pool_wallet_report(sys_account_id in number) return sys_refcursor as
   p_recordset sys_refcursor;
begin
   open p_recordset for
      select status
            ,reconciliation
            ,count(*) as no_of_transactions
            ,sum(ybl_commission) as commission
            ,sum(merchant_payable) as merchant_payable
            ,sum(amount) as total_amount
        from fund_transfers
       where system_account_id = sys_account_id
         and neutralize = 0
       group by status
               ,reconciliation
       order by status         desc
               ,reconciliation desc;
   return p_recordset;
end;
```

which works fine when it is created. but after some time or next day ti start throwing erros "function in invalid state"

Comment: What are you doing when you see that error? Does the `user_errors` table show what is actually wrong with it at that point? And does rebuilding the function, or doing `alter function payu_pool_wallet_report compile`, fix it? If it is being invalidated that suggests that perhaps `fund_transfers` is being modified (drop/recreate); but the function shoudl alutomatically recompile itself next time it's referenced anyway.

Comment: Yes, when I rebuilding the function it again works fine.There is nothing in user_errors table.

Comment: Objects in oracle will be invalidated every time an object on which they are dependent gets altered.  It's an indication to the compiler to first compile the procedure before executing it.  Check for code changing the table fund_transfers.